# setvalue/addvalue in webdriverio is not working for web element when executing in microsoft edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, webdriver-io

setvalue/addvalue is not working for web element when script execution done in microsoft edge.
In microsoft edge, after 60 secs, function gets timeout error.
For the same web element i tried with chrome browser, it works fine. can some help

Answer (score 0):

Start debugging the Problem - believe me it will get solved

1 Are you able to perform any operation on Edge using WebdriverIo ?

Hoping your locator is correct , if not please check once